# How do I pass arguments via bash to Python when running a script

Tags: python, bash, arguments

How do I pass arguments to a python script when running it from Bash?

```
python somepythonfile.py arg1 arg2
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the command that you provided?

Comment: The args are taken to be part of what I pass to python.  I need the args accessible form the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, you can get raw access to the args via `sys.argv`

For more complicated handling of arguments, if making a command line script, you may want to check out the argparse module:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

(from the docs...)

For example, consider a file named `myprogram.py` with the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

From the command line:

```
$ python myprogram.py --help
usage: myprogram.py [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --foo FOO   foo help
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how you have. You can access them via `sys.argv`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Outputs:

```
Number of arguments: 3 arguments
Argument List: ['somepythonfile.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

- Argument 0 (`sys.argv[0]`) is the name of the script
- Argument 1 through Argument N  (`sys.argv[1]` ... `sys.argv[N]`) are the passed arguments

Shamelessly taken from [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Use sys.argv, which is a list containing the arguments passed to your script as well as the filename.

```
# test_prog.py
from sys import argv

print argv[0] # test_prog.py
if len(argv) > 1: # check that we have at least 1 argument
    print argv[1]
```